# SVN update authentication request on some directories

Tags: svn

When I issue svn update command on directories with the same user and group permissions, sometimes I get password prompt and sometimes I don't. How can I go about debugging this? What triggers such authentication on what seems to me directories with same permissions?

thanks!

Comment: Subversion asks for your password for access to the Subversion *server*, not to your local files. Are your different directories pointing at the same repository? Try `svn info` in each directory.

Comment: Another possibility is that your browser (or subversion client) is caching the credentials for some of the repositories, but not others.

Comment: Greg,
Thanks for svn info tip.

I did svn info in directory that does not ask for password and repository root starts with file:// protocol, whereas when I am being asked for password repository root starts with svn+ssh protocol. As a test I checked out project from svn point to repository using file:// protocol and in fact svn update works without authentication request.
So when I am being authenticated for directories with svn+ssh repository root, does it mean that my credentials are not cached somewhere? And if so, how do I persist my credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Put your username/password (your svn account) directly into the command line:

```
svn --username <> --password <> update
```

Comment: worked for me. After this command it shows "Store password unencrypted (yes/no)?". yes. Then no more password asking.

Answer (score 0):

With svn+ssh protocol the ssh component will ask you for the password.
[How to setup ssh that it will not ask for a password.](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)